# In line error validation

Tags: javascript

I have a question and im not quite sure what would be the proper terminology.

I have a text box in a form.

When the use fills out some information i would like to check the text box and if there is an error show the error next to the textbox. An alert would work as will but prefer the in line error.

Comment: Easiest validation I've used is jQuery's validator plugin. Very simple, you can write custom rules, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using jQuery here is some really basic validation:

```
$(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function () {
        var $input = $('#textbox');

        // Make some validation againts the textbox here
        if ('' === $input.text()) {
            $input.after('<span class="error">Invalid value.</span>');

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
});
```

But as above pointed out, instead of reinventing the wheel look for some existing solution, for example the jquery validate plugin.